# Windows 10 browser search redirects to company website

Tags: windows-10, firefox, browser, internet-explorer

I recently dusted off a somewhat older laptop that I used at my last job. I noticed that whenever I type something followed by a forward slash into the address bar on any browser I get redirected to the home page for one of the companies I did contract work for at my old job. For example, typing "test/" into Firefox or IE routes me to the company website instead of searching the web or whatever the default behaviour should be.
[Example GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZnVA.gif)

I have vague memories of having to configure weird internet settings for some of the clients I worked with but it's been so long I can't remember what I did. I'd like to rid this PC of any connection to the clients from my old job as I'm no longer associated with any of them.

Comment: Most likely has a proxy setting (even a proxy app) doing this.

Comment: The best course of action is to reinstall the whole OS from an updated installer. In the end this will save time and provide better results.